# django-cms, django flatpages, tiny mce not displaying

Tags: django, tinymce, django-flatpages

I've implemented both django-cms and flatpages, but can not get tiny_mce to display in either.

urls.py

```
(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        )
```

settings.py

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/js/tinymce/'
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
   'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
   'theme': "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}

TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = False
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = False
TINYMCE_FILEBROWSER = True
CMS_USE_TINYMCE = True
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatPageAdmin
#Flatpages
class FlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
              'http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js',)

# We have to unregister it, and then reregister
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageAdmin)
#django-cms
from myprograms.cms.models import Page
class PageOptions(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
              'http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js')
#admin.site.register(Page, PageOptions)
```

In the base.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url tinymce-js "NAME" %}"></script>
```

There are so many different options when accessing the various user groups, docs, etc.  I'm not sure what is the correct syntax.  The CMS doesn't do me much good without some kind of text editor.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all please check this line with slash like:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>`

also please check site_id in error logs. had similar issue with site_id because I created new site with different id.

Best,
Mykola Lys.

Answer (score 1):

If you need some more features then the simple flatpages just checkout django-blocks (http://code.google.com/p/django-blocks/). Has multi-language Menu, Flatpages and even has a simple Shopping Cart!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [TinyMCE page on the Django wiki](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor)? Also - although it looks like it might not apply to you - [browsers block calls from scripts across differing servers/domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572025/tiny-mce-popups-blank-in-django-admin/1158623#1158623)...