# TinyMCE empty link popup

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When I try to insert a link using the TinyMCE link plugin all that happens is I get an empty popup box.

It continuously tries to load:

```
tiny_mce/utils/mctabs.js
tiny_mce/utils/form_utils.js
tiny_mce/utils/validate.js
tiny_mce/themes/advanced/js/link.js
```

I've seen solutions where you need to edit a config.php file, but I only have the JS version of TinyMCE

Comment: Are you attempting to the scripts load it remotely? [Looking at this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572025/tiny-mce-popups-blank-in-django-admin)..
Could you post the code you are using to load TinyMCE or some context information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens to me all the time in Opera, but not in other browsers. Try refreshing the empty popup you get and you'll probably get its contents.