# Amazon S3 static web hosting not working with custom domain name (dot issue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, domain-name

I followed the instruction on S3 doc to host a static website there. Everything works with the domain name provided by S3. I can access "examplebucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

However, when I forward my own custom domain name, the domain name provider added a dot at the very end of my domain, then it's like I'm accessing "examplebucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.", this won't work because Amazon thinks you're accessing a different address. And then give me 404 error.

Is there any workaround for this? or any place I should set up in S3?

Comment: I think you might be misdiagnosing this, since a CNAME referencing a different domain than the zone where the CNAME itself is defined... always has to end with a dot. That's normal, and shouldn't break anything.

Comment: Also... the hostname of your web site (the one you're "forwarding") has to be *exactly* the same as the name of the bucket. The web site "example.com" can only work in a bucket called "example.com" while the web site "www.example.com" can *only* work in a bucket called "www.example.com" ... the two aren't interchangeable, and you can't successfully map a domain name to a bucket by any other name using DNS and S3 static web site hosting.  Is this what you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is too late for the original question but there may be more people with the same issues (me last week).

I was having the same issue while trying to create a route in route53 with CloudFormation. I was trying to redirect my domain `www.example.com` to `example-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

It turns out you cannot redirect to an arbitrary bucket. The bucket name must be the same as the domain you're trying to alias. So if you want to redirect `www.example.com`, your bucket name must be `www.example.com` and the URL must be `www.example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

Moreover cloudformation has a weird syntax. Cloudformation doesn't need the name of the bucket (it already knows it). It only needs the endpoint.

So instead of using something like

```
"AliasTarget": {
               "DNSName" : "example-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
               "HostedZoneId" : "<zoneID>"
             },
```

you need

```
"AliasTarget": {
               "DNSName" : "s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
               "HostedZoneId" : "<zoneID>"
             },
```

And route53 where to redirect because the name of the route must be the same as the name of the bucket.

Related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048129/54256