# How can I assign a subdomain to my AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have a file in my AWS bucket: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.my-company.com/media/my-file.jpg`.

Currently I'm accessing that file in my `index.html` file `www.my-company.com`. I have `my-company.com` as a hosted zone in AWS Route 53.

But in that `index.html`, I don't want it to be obvious that this asset is in an AWS bucket. I want it to appear as if it is hosted in on my own domain's servers. So instead of `https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.my-company.com/media/my-file.jpg`, I want it to be addressed as `https://static.my-company.com/media/my-file.jpg`. How can I do that?

I tried inserting a CNAME record in Route 53 that would point `static.my-company.com` to `s3.amazonaws.com/static.my-company.com`. But that didn't work. That's what Jay Godse recommended [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048129/1742777)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your S3 bucket as a **Static Website** (it's an option in S3 to set your bucket as such). The domain name will then change to something like `http://static.my-company.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.`, which is what you will want to set the CNAME record to in Route 53.

Note that you cannot set a CNAME record to a directory like you are currently doing, it has to be a resolvable domain.

Comment: Correct, except this doesn't support HTTPS and the `us-east-1` will vary with the region where the bucket was created. The correct endpoint for a bucket is found [in the console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2019 : AWS Subdomain hosting in S3**

Following steps worked  for me to have a subdomain working on AWS S3 hosted static website :

1. Create a bucket with subdomain name. In example below it will be www.**subtest**.mysite.com

[image: aws bucket]

Note: Make sure on 'Permission' tab of bucket following is set:

1.Block public access (bucket settings)
2.Access Control List
3.Bucket policy
are appropriately set to make sure bucket is public. ( Assuming you already did this for your root domain bucket, those settings can be mirrored on this subdomain bucket)

[image: S3 bucket permissions]

2. Upload the **index.html** file in the bucket

[image: index aws bucket]

3. Create a **CNAME record** with your domain provider
   [image: CNAME record in namecheap]

Answer (score 1):

> So instead of `https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.my-company.com/media/my-file.jpg`, I want it to be addressed as `https://static.my-company.com/media/my-file.jpg`. How can I do that?

There are three separate issues, here.

If you enable the web site hosting feature for your bucket, as @Deif illustrates in another answer here, you can point the hostname in Route 53 to the bucket's web site endpoint using an Alias or CNAME and it works.  But it doesn't support HTTPS.

HTTPS requires that the web server identify itself to the browser with an SSL (TLS) certificate that includes a hostname matching the one in the browser's address box.  The S3 certificates on the REST endpoint match various permutations of `s3.amazonaws.com` --  they don't match your domain.

So you need an SSL certificate.  If you already have one, upload it into Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) in the us-east-1 region.¹  If not, ACM can create one for you for free.

Next, create a new CloudFront distribution, using your subdomain as an Alternate Domain Name, using the ACM certificate above, and using your web site endpoint hostname as the Origin Server.

Then, point your subdomain in Route 53 to the CloudFront distribution.

Now, `https://subdomain.example.com/pics/funny/cat.jpg` goes to CloudFront which provides SSL and fetches the content from the appropriate bucket.

Why is CloudFront necessary?  That's the official solution for using a custom domain name with SSL enabled with S3.  S3 doesn't support the capability natively.  Using CloudFront has an accompanying cost, but it significantly reduces the cost of S3 itself.  When a download occurs through CloudFront, S3 charges $0 for the bandwidth used for the download and CloudFront bills the bandwidth instead.  The CloudFront price for bandwidth is lower in many cases (presumably because CloudFront can scale horizontally to alleviate congestion, while S3 can only scale vertically -- it is location constrained by design).

---

¹ In ACM, the `us-east-1` region is always used for the setup I describe here, regardless of the bucket location because CloudFront is managed out of us-east-1 and we need this certificate to be accessible to CloudFront.