# TinyMCE Popups coming up blank

Tags: tinymce

I've looked through several posts asking about this issue, but I have not been able to resolve it - and the error message I'm now getting makes no sense to me.

I have TinyMCE added to a text area as follows:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode : "textareas",
    relative_urls: true,
    plugins : "inlinepopups",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    theme_advanced_path : false,
    theme_advanced_resizing_min_width : 600,
    theme_advanced_resizing_max_width : 800
});
```

When I open the page, it gives me the following error:

**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.mysite.com/mypage from frame with URL http://www.mysite.com/js/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/link.htm. Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

From what I can tell, this error is caused if you try to access JavaScript across domains. However, the domains appear to be the same (the only thing I changed was the actual site name and the actual page - the rest is copied letter for letter).

In the file tiny_mce_popup.js I have added `document.domain = 'www.mysite.com';` as per some suggestions, but it does not seem to help. If I add it to tiny_mce.js, I get an error that I have an invalid document.domain value.

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The script tag where I include TinyMCE is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Comment: Added the <script> tag to the question.

Comment: Tried that, and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This might allply to you too: [Tiny MCE popups blank in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572025/tiny-mce-popups-blank-in-django-admin)

Athother reason for your issue might be that your webserver (e.g.: Apache) is not configured be configured to serve static media files from your media_url.