# Django Serve Static Files - correct URL settings for Django-Storages

Tags: django, deployment

I'm just crushing my head about how to setup my URL settings in order they serve the static files correctly.

For development my URL settings look like this.

```
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
```

But I assume I have to change this setting because django.views.static.serve is intended to be used only for development. At least this was stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/static-files/#the-big-fat-disclaimer) for Django 1.1. Whereas no disclaimer to be found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/) for Django 1.4, which I'm currently using.

I'm using [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) with s3 to serve the static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [django cumulus](https://github.com/richleland/django-cumulus) 
It has great documentation, i've used it successfully to serve static files from amazon and rackspace cdn

Cumulus docs will show you exactly what to do in your settings file for static config

If you don't want to -  set your static URL to your amazon bucket
in my case i'm using rackspace so my static url looks like:
    STATIC_URL = '//csk3ls.r93.d2.rackcdn.com/'

Comment: Thanks. Want to stay with django storages. I know that I have to set the STATIC_URL. I m wondering if it is fine to use django.views.static.serve in production?

Comment: Yes it is. Sometimes I use static serve to serve specific kinds of files that have cross domain problems when serving from the cloud see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572025/tiny-mce-popups-blank-in-django-admin/10149491#10149491

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to add anything to your urls.py file as your files are served from S3.

use the django [builtin view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) for your development server and for production, just set the rights paths for STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in your settings.py file.

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/yourbucket/'
```

Comment: WHOLE day on this F'ing issue.  OMG.  THanks so much Otacon!!